# Switchyard. How to create singleton service?

Tags: java, switchyard

What i'm trying to do is next:
I have dispatcher that will receive messages of different types and route them to handlers. Dispatcher holds map of , every MessageHandler can process his type of messages, and every handler should register in dispatcher.

So i have "Dispatcher" service which implement interface:

```
public interface Dispatcher{
   public void register(IMessageHandler handler);
   public void handle(IMessage message);
}
```

and several beans that implement interface IMessageHandler:

```
public interface IMessageHandler{
   public void handle(IMessage message);
}
```

IMessage is also an interface.

I need this instances of IMessageHandler to call "register" method on Dispatcher to register themself, so dispatcher can distribute messages to appropriate handlers.

For now i do next:

```
@Service(IMessageHandler.class)
public class MessageBHandler implements IMessageHandler {

    @Inject
    @Reference
    Dispatcher dispatcher;

  @PostConstruct
  public void registerMyself(){
     dispatcher.register(this);
  }
...

}
```

But i see in logs that Dispatcher gets create twice.
How can i make him singleton?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify the scope of your Dispacher implementation, it defaults to the *@Dependent* scope. That means that there will be a different *Dispacher* instance for each *MessageHandler*.

Try setting the scope of your Dispacher implementation to *@ApplicationScoped*.

See: [Using Scopes](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbbk.html).